# reading value with nodejs

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read a value from Vault using the NodeJS. I am posting here to ensure my approach is correct.

Using the https://github.com/kr1sp1n/node-vault library, I have the following snippet of code:

```
var params = {
  apiVersion: 'v1',
  endpoint: "https://localhost:8200",
  token: "MY_TOKEN"
};

   var vault = require("node-vault")(params);
   vault.read('secret/mysecret/foo').then(v => {
     console.log(v);
   }).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

This returns the following block of JSON to me:

```
{ request_id: 'MY_ID',
  lease_id: '',
  renewable: false,
  lease_duration: 100,
  data: { value: 'MY_PASSWORD' },
  wrap_info: null,
  warnings: null,
  auth: null }
```

Specifically, I need to fetch the value of data.value (i.e. I need to fetch 'MY_PASSWORD'.

Would I perform JSON parsing within the 'then' block instead of printing the JSON to the console log like I am currently?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because `vault.read()` is asynchronous you need to access and parse the return value in the `then()`

```
vault.read('secret/mysecret/foo').then(v => {
    let parsed = JSON.parse(v);
    let pw = parsed.data.value //=> 'MY_PASSWORD'
}).catch(e => console.error(e));
```

Obviously, you'll probably want to do some error checks to make sure you have good json  data, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The `vault.read()` call returns a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and the '[then](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then)' method will be executed once the promise resolves. So, yes, you should be parsing it in there.